# What resistor to use with LEDs in 18 V circuit?

Tags: led, resistors

I've got a circuit with two 9 V batteries in series powering 8 LEDs (amateur stuff, don't worry, it's nothing important). It was flickering before and now I have reason to believe at least one has failed, so yeah was definitely pumping too much voltage through them.

Don't know what resistor to put in, honestly all the explanations of this stuff are way beyond me. Can someone tell me what to use or is it not that simple?

Comment: Of course it is not that simple. You haven't even told how the LEDs are connected. Are they all in series, all in parallel, or some mixed combination of series and parallel? What's the LED rated forward voltage and current? Are they regular LEDs that work with few mA or multi-watt LEDs intended for luminaries? If all else is unknown, maybe a photo of them and colour of the light would help; like red, green, blue or white.

Comment: What colour LEDs? (affects voltrage drop per LED). | Series or parallel? |  A photo showing LED connections would greatly  help.

Answer (score 3):

820 ohms.

This assumes a low LED voltage of 1.3V (probably actually closer to 1.7 for red, a bit higher for other colors, up to ~2.3 for white). It also assumes a constant 9V each from your batteries, which will very quickly drop to ~8 volts under load.  Finally, it limits the current through the (I assume) series-connected string to 10mA which is low-average for through hole 3mm or 5mm LEDs. The result will probably be a bit dim, but you can buy a resistor kit for cheap and try lower values; I wouldn't go much lower than 220 ohms.

For reference the equation is (battery voltage - LED forward voltage)/desired LED current.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I dont know the exact voltage for these LED's unfortunately but that gives me a range of ohms to play with. These are to illuminate a some stuff on a cosplay so i may try on the lower end to get them a bit brighter.

Answer (score 1):

A red LED usually takes about 1.7V, with 8 such LEDs in series they drop 13.6V while you have 18V available.  So you have 4.4V to waste on typically 20mA (see the problem?  You don't give any details about the LEDs you actually use), meaning a resistor of 220 ohms.

Now make no mistake: LEDs rated for 20mA and getting 20mA are conspicuous.  It may well be that this is annoyingly bright for your application.  Indicator LEDs can typically get away with 2mA or so, but for illumination you'd usually go brighter.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I originally set the circuit up a long time ago so i don't know the exact LED voltage unfortunately (iirc it didn't say on the box anyway), but this should be enough info to know what kind of resistors to test.

It's to illuminate a cosplay prop so brighter is better in this instance, hence why I'm using 8 haha